# Can the portworx "internal" kvdb coexist with etcd?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a tiny (three worker node, one controlplane) kubernetes cluster running and I want to configure portworx for storage. All my hosts are kvm virtual machines running Ubuntu 20.4.3 LTS with 5.4.0-73-generic kernel. I used https://central.portworx.com/specGen/wizard to generate a portworx 2.8.1.2-c9b840b (OCI) spec file and applied it to my cluster. I chose to *not* configure a dedicated kvdb drive on these hosts although each host *does* have a sdb intended as the portworx drive. (These sdb drives are not mounted.)

When I run **pxctl status** I see:

> NODE    NodeStartFailure        3a5bce08-b8ed-4fca-93a2-435a8d6e512b    ALARM           1       Jan 9 18:31:45 UTC 2022 Jan 9 18:31:45 UTC 2022        > Could not find any available storage disks on this node. Node cannot act as a kvdb node as no storage device found. Waiting for other nodes to start kvdb. > If this is a storage node please add disks and restart Portworx.

> NODE    InternalKvdbSetupFailed 907d5a2c-297d-4587-87f8-31d539cff440    ALARM           1       Jan 9 18:31:10 UTC 2022 Jan 9 18:31:10 UTC 2022        failed to setup internal kvdb: failed to provision internal kvdb: timeout waiting for other kvdb nodes to start: Could not find any available storage disks on this node. Node cannot act as a kvdb node as no storage device found. Waiting for other nodes to start kvdb. If this is a storage node please add disks and restart Portworx.

I would rather use etcd instead of kvdb. Does anyone care to comment? Also, is the portworx operator intended for kubernetes?

oops. I just noticed this on the portworx website:

```
PX-Essentials support only built-in KVDB.
External ETCD is accessible in PX-Enterprise
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post your edit as an answer, and accept it. This way the question won't stay unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

PX-Essentials supports only built-in KVDB.
External ETCD is accessible in PX-Enterprise